# How to call .dtsx file which has input parameters from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, etl

How to call .dtsx package file which has input parameters from a stored procedure?

Stored Procedure # 1 -> Will pass the list of files to be exported to excel as a Comma Separated value in a variable.

Input variable will be passed to the SSIS Package to export the data to excel.

How to handle the SSIS Package which has Input parameters from a Stored Procedure call?

Comment: i think you have an amazing working answer, why not accepting it??

Comment: @goofyui is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using DtExec and xp_cmdshell

One way to do that is to run DtExec utility from file system using xp_cmdshell utility inside sql server.

First you have to enable the `xp_cmdshell` utility:

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
-- WITH OVERRIDE disables the configuration value checking if the value is valid
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
-- To enable the xp_cmdshell component.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE 
GO
-- Revert back the advance option
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
GO 
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE 
GO
```

Then you can use the following command to execute the package and pass avariable value as parameter:

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS VARCHAR(2000)

DECLARE @ServerName VARCHAR(200) = 'ARSHAD-LAPPY' 

SET @SQLQuery = 'DTExec /FILE ^"E:\DataTransfer.dtsx^" '
SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' /SET \Package.Variables[ServerName].Value;^"'+ @ServerName + '^"'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @SQLQuery
GO
```

---

## References

- [Executing a SSIS Package from Stored Procedure in SQL Server](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/executing-a-ssis-package-from-stored-procedure-in-sql-server.html)
- [Run an SSIS package from the command prompt with DTExec.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-cmdline?view=sql-server-2017)
- [DTEXEC Command Line Parameters Using Command Files](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1812/dtexec-command-line-parameters-using-command-files/)
- [dtexec Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

## Helpful links

- [How to Call SSIS Package from the Stored Procedure](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27156/How-to-Call-SSIS-Package-from-the-Stored-Procedure)
- [Run an SSIS package from SSMS with Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/deploy-and-execute-ssis-packages-using-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-2014) *(if using SSISDB)*
- [How To Execute an Integration Services (SSIS) Package from a SQL Server Stored Procedure](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2992/how-to-execute-an-integration-services-ssis-package-from-a-sql-server-stored-procedure/) *(if using SSISDB)*